# Disable Eclipse warning about generated html?

Tags: html, apache-flex, eclipse

When developing Flex projects, Eclipse gives warnings about the default `index.html` file generated by Flex Builder. The file is in the 'target' folder (or "generated artifacts" folder. Yes, I'm also using Maven). Can I eliminate or disable this warning?

The code which generates the warning is below, though I would definitely prefer not changing the html - as I say this is the template suggested by Adobe. Eclipse warns of "Undefined attribute name (xxx)" for `scroll` on the `body` tag, and most of the `embed` attributes.

There is no `DOCTYPE` declaration in the html file.

```
<html lang="en">
...
<body scroll="no">
...

    <embed src="myswf.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
         width="100%" height="100%" name="myswf-flex" align="middle"
         play="true"
         loop="false"
         quality="high"
         allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options. The simplest way is to filter the target folder from the package explorer.

On the Package Explorer view there is a little downwards pointing triangle on the top right of the view (with tooltip View Menu), Click on that and select **Filters...**. On the dialog check **Name filter patterns (matching items will be hidden):** and type *target* in the field. The target folder should now be hidden and errors for the target folder suppressed.

A few other alternatives to try: On the **Problems** view, select the View Menu triangle
and select **Configure Contents**.

In the dialog, you can:

1. Uncheck the **HTML Problem** item in the **Types** list. Obviously this disables all HTML problems which isn't great.
2. In the **Scope** section, select **On working set:**. To create a new working set, choose **Select...**, create a new working set for the project that includes everything except target.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a global validation filter based on directory. I can set the scope filter (your option #2) which hides 'target' warnings in the Problems view, but icon overlays in both Navigator and Explorer still show the warning up the directory structure to the basdir. Based on that I expect setting filters on the Navigator or Explorer would only apply to that view. It's a good start though. --

Note, I'm unable to set Navigator filters, but that may be a new Eclipse 3.5.x (galileo) feature (I'm on 3.4.x, ganymede).